# Get grouped tableview background color in my view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background-color

I want to use the background color/pattern of the grouped tableview in my view, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yep, use the [`+[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW41):

```
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
```

Comment: Don't use this as this is now deprecated in iOS6 (it will give blank) See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452810/is-grouptableviewbackgroundcolor-deprecated-on-ios-6

Comment: Seems like it's fine to use this again, as right now it's not marked as depreciated in the documentation. (I'm guessing it's used again since iOS 7, with the introduction of the flat designs?)